# Do nano simcards performs better than a normal sim card?

Tags: nano, sim

I wonder if a nano simcard has any capability to perform better than that of a normal or micro sim card other than it's considerable size difference.I heard that's these nano ones have much more speed while accessing data.Is that true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the size differences there is no absolute performance differences in the SIM. And when it comes to SIM cards, it really does matter. Some phones can’t handle a regular SIM card, and others can’t even handle the micro SIM card. As technology keeps on advancing, it seems that these cards are just getting smaller and smaller and maybe someday they'll come inbuilt to our phones.

Having said that, when it comes to designing a PCB layout for a device, having multiple small components is more favourable than having big ones, because small components can be moved around more freely when designing the layout, leading to smaller and thinner phones.

Hope this helps your question :)

Comment: That's all i needed ! Just wanted to know if there is anything with the performance.Thanks !

Comment: @AJITH glad to help u out.